# Guacamole error: Remote Desktop server is currently unreachable

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, rdp, guacamole

I have setup a Guacamole server on Ubuntu 16.04 with Tomcat7. Everything was working great. I added a second database for a side script that i'm running. Went to log back into my Guac server and I can still reach the login page, but once I try to login I get the error message: Remote desktop server is currently unreachable, trying again in 15 seconds. I am never able to reach the Guac web application (aside from the login screen).

/var/log/syslog shows me this: (not very helpful)

```
Jan 30 22:08:26 ip-172-31-0-87 guacd[1186]: Creating new client for protocol "rdp"
Jan 30 22:08:26 ip-172-31-0-87 guacd[1186]: Connection ID is "$7d0b76dc-1232-4f14-ad7c-f3e775479918"
Jan 30 22:08:26 ip-172-31-0-87 guacd[1591]: Security mode: TLS
Jan 30 22:08:26 ip-172-31-0-87 guacd[1591]: Resize method: none
Jan 30 22:08:26 ip-172-31-0-87 guacd[1591]: User "@b3a396a9-8c60-484e-961a-cfbc0e3bd941" joined connection "$7d0b76dc-1232-4f14-ad7c-f3e775479918" (1 users now present)
Jan 30 22:08:26 ip-172-31-0-87 guacd[1591]: Loading keymap "base"
Jan 30 22:08:26 ip-172-31-0-87 guacd[1591]: Loading keymap "en-us-qwerty"
Jan 30 22:08:29 ip-172-31-0-87 guacd[1591]: Error connecting to RDP server
Jan 30 22:08:29 ip-172-31-0-87 guacd[1591]: User "@b3a396a9-8c60-484e-961a-cfbc0e3bd941" disconnected (0 users remain)
Jan 30 22:08:29 ip-172-31-0-87 guacd[1591]: Last user of connection "$7d0b76dc-1232-4f14-ad7c-f3e775479918" disconnected
Jan 30 22:08:29 ip-172-31-0-87 guacd[1186]: Connection "$7d0b76dc-1232-4f14-ad7c-f3e775479918" removed.
```

Things I have tried:

- Added guacd-hostname and guacd-port to guacamole.properties file
- Rebooted the system
- Restarted Guacd service
- Tried to change logging to "debug" with a logback.xml file but that didn't seem to change anything, or I don't know where I'm looking

Things that might have caused this:
- I created a new ubuntu user and setup a web root folder under their home dir
- Changed owner of this /home/~username/public_html folder to the apache user "www-data" (this might have affected other folders?)
- Installed phpMyAdmin

This is running in AWS. No security groups or IPs have changed since it was working.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, it was a "feature" and not a bug.

When I first setup guac I made one connection to test it out.

As it turns out, when you make a single connection in guac, the next time you login it will automatically try to connect to that single connection you've made bypassing the setup screen completely.

Since i'm in the habit of trashing AWS instances frequently, that instance had already been terminated a while back. Little did I know that guac would continue to try to connect to that instance even though it no longer existed and unless you know the magic key combo of "shift+ctrl+alt". There is no way to get to the guac settings screen to remove the connection and add new ones, and nothing I came across mentioned this. It should probably make be made a little more clear during setup.

Case closed.

Comment: Didn't really get the cause of your problem, your guacd and guacamole servers were on different AWS instances?

Comment: I only had one remote host to connect to within gauc. I trashed that remote host instance but gauc was still trying to connect to it without prompting me to try to connect to a different host instead.

I expected to hit a setup page that asks you which host you are trying to connect to, but gauc bypasses the setup page when you only have one host configured. Hopefully that makes sense.